# CSS3 Circular Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've found [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/index2.html) beautiful circular menu and I'm struggling to adapt it to my own needs.

I only need four items from that menu and their 'width' (horizontal space) should be increased.

I've put the original code in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNrAF/). The version with four items is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SNrAF/1/).

As previously said, I'm trying to fill that empty space between by increasing their size because I'd like to fit more text in there.

Part of the CSS that I think it might be relevant:

```
.csstransforms .cn-wrapper li {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -1.3em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
    transform: rotate(76deg) skew(60deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: You are aware that the link on the top right of the demo page leads to an article actually explaining the technique in more detail, right …?

Comment: I'm working on a solution, but I have one comment:  Having an even number of items won't look as cool as having an odd number because it can't come out in the center.  Could you use 5 or 3?

Comment: This is likely being done through compiled css with something like Less or Compass. If you want to modify this on by hand, Looking at the [interactive demo][1] is really helpful. Basically you can adjust the skew on the li's (the parallelograms) and adjust the skew and rotation on the anchors until you get the desired shape. Unfortunately it would take a lot of trial and error to find the right one. I would suggest using some kind of compiled less to do it or a one off javascript method to calculate it.


  [1]: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CircularNavigation/interactivedemo/index.html

Comment: thanks for the input guys. 
@SuperScript: unfortunately i need four. I'm fine as long as they are evenly spaced and as I said, have room for more text (not a lot more, a little more than what it has in the last fiddle i mentioned).
for Chris: I've tried playing a lot with those values from the chrome console, but I just couldn't do it and thought about asking here on SO, hoping somebody would be better than me at CSS3.

Comment: That is a way cool animation.  I'm glad you asked it on Stackoverflow just so people (like me) could see it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to mess with the `transform` `skew`.

```
transform: rotate(...) skew(40deg);
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robbiewxyz/zpTyH/) for the solution.

(P.S. That's a way cool menu animation!)

Comment: Way to go @SuperScript.  That's some killer CSS